# Compare Enum Angular 4

Tags: angular

oportunidad.model.ts:

```
const enum TipoSiNo {
SI, NO
}


export class Oportunidad {
constructor(
  public resultadoValidacion?: TipoSiNo,
```

I need to buy the value of my object with one of the possible values of the enumerated:

oportunidad-edit.component.ts:

add:

```
const enum TipoSiNo {
SI, NO
}

this.oportunidad.resultadoValidacion === TipoSiNo.NO
```

Give me the following error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/main/webapp/app/entities/oportunidad/oportunidad-edit.component.ts:337:75 
TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'TipoSiNo.NO' and 'TipoSiNo.NO'.
```

Comment: Why not use a simple boolean instead of YES/NO (SI/NO) in this case?

Comment: Because it is not a boolean, it does something different if it is null, true or false.

Comment: The question was whether you really need to use an enum or if it could be a boolean instead. Well see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11533) bug and consider upgrading TypeScript or simply use == because enums are static values so there is no benefit using ===

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.oportunidad.resultadoValidacion as TipoSiNo === TipoSiNo.NO as TipoSiNo
```

Comment: It is comparing the String with the position. What's in front of the "===" is "SI" but what's in the second part is 0, you know how to fix it.

Comment: You mean you want to compare string 'SI' with enum type TipoSiNo.SI? Why do you need the enum? I think you can use string 'SI' and 'NO' directly...

Comment: I do not care if I compared YES === YES or with the 0 === 0 position, the problem is that now it does YES === 0 and therefore the condition is never met. I need the first value to be the position, or the second value is the String.

Comment: Well, what's the value of this.oportunidad.resultadoValidacion now? A string or enum?

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are creating the same enum: `TipoSiNo` at two different places and hence both are two different types so the comparison is not going to work.

I came here to find why I can't compare the two enum values from the same enum, but couldn't really get any answer anywhere. Example:

```ts
export enum Stage{
NotStarted, QuarterOf, Half, QuarterTo, Full
}

export class Work{
id: number,
title: string,
description: string,
status: Stage
}

// check if work is not started
if(this.currentWork===Stage.NotStarted){ // <- this is never true
   // do something
}
```

So, I found a workaround:

```ts
// check if work is not started
if(this.currentWork.toString===Stage[Stage.NotStarted]){ // <- this works
   // do something
}
```

Hopefully, it helps someone